# SSL Error on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I've got the "Your connection is not private" when I want to have access to a site that I know is sure (and I don't have the proceed button).
I can't find the " Remember decisions to proceed through SSL errors for a specified length of time" in the Chrome flags. (Chrome is 46.0.2490.80, on os x 10.9.5)
Is there another way to have access to this webpage ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used the "danger" trick (When on the webpage, you type danger on your keyboard and have access to the page). I am not sure why it works, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's built in the browser, as of January 2016 now the keyword is "badidea"

Here's how it "works":

```
/**
 * This allows errors to be skippped by typing "danger" into the page.
 * @param {string} e The key that was just pressed.
 */
function handleKeypress(e) {
  var BYPASS_SEQUENCE = 'badidea';
  if (BYPASS_SEQUENCE.charCodeAt(keyPressState) == e.keyCode) {
    keyPressState++;
    if (keyPressState == BYPASS_SEQUENCE.length) {
      sendCommand(CMD_PROCEED);
      keyPressState = 0;
    }
  } else {
    keyPressState = 0;
  }
}
```

[...]

```
/**
 * A convenience method for sending commands to the parent page.
 * @param {string} cmd  The command to send.
 */
function sendCommand(cmd) {
  window.domAutomationController.setAutomationId(1);
  window.domAutomationController.send(cmd);
}
```

[Here's the chromium js file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/90b6605758feea9d4f2a56ad3f6992e1e868b445/components/security_interstitials/core/browser/resources/interstitial_v2.js)

Comment: I love how they changed the magic word, but did not modify the comment up to date. Programmers are so much alike, even at the top level.